# text replace with js (keep uc)

Tags: javascript

I have made this script and i have a question:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('html').html(function(i, v) {
    var searchMask = "think";
    var regEx = new RegExp(searchMask, "ig");
    return v.replace(regEx, '<span style="background-color:yellow;">$&</span>');
  });
});
```

```html
<p id="demo">String replace. any Think new replace</p>
```

This script take a word inside the html like "think" and replace it with a background-color span with the searched word inside.

If you see the fiddle initially "think" had the "T" capital, after the replacement was of course changed to tiny "t". I would like the script to always keep case sensitive, can this be done with js?

I want to be able to change the words by searching them with the tiny ones.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GHQU6/9/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could insert the found string with [`$&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) into the replacement.

```js
var searchMask = "think",
    regEx = new RegExp(searchMask, "ig"),
    v = 'THINK, but do not think too much!';

document.body.innerHTML += v.replace(regEx, '<span style="background-color:yellow;">$&</span>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're replacing with `searchMask` and `searchMask = "think"`

Change it to `Think`. There is an exact word replace is happening.

You can change it to `&$` to replace with found word.

```
return v.replace(regEx, '<span style="background-color:yellow;">$&</span>');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('html').html(function(i, v) {


    var searchMask = "think";
    var regEx = new RegExp(searchMask, "ig");

    return v.replace(regEx, '<span style="background-color:yellow;">$&</span>');



  });
});
```

```html
<p id="demo">String replace. any Think new replace</p>
```

Comment: I want to be able to change the words by searching them with the tiny ones, but keepeng uppercase (if have).

Comment: check the snippet. you can use `$&` to replace with match @NicolaFerioli